# typedef in cocoa blocks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have a simple Blocks and typedef doubt.
Consider the following codes, I've some typedef and two methods, second one is commented out. My doubt is regarding the first one. Should I use this one? Any issues or something that may arise in future?

```
typedef void (^MySuccessBlock)(MyServiceResponse *response); 
typedef void (^MyFailureBlock)(NSError *errorObject);

@property (nonatomic, copy)MySuccessBlock mySuccessBlock; 
@property (nonatomic, copy)MyFailureBlock myFailureBlock;

//SHOULD I USE THIS?
- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:mySuccessBlock
                          failure:myFailureBlock; 

//- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:(void (^)(MyServiceResponse *response))completion 
//                        failure:(void (^)(NSError *errorObject))failure;
```

In Implementation file:

```
//If 1st one is used:
- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:aSuccessBlock
                          failure:aFailureBlock{

    self.mySuccessBlock = aSuccessBlock;
    self.myFailureBlock = aFailureBlock;

    ....
}
```

Comment: How can you pass the property to method definition like that

Comment: @Anoop Its perfectly fine to use this, we have used this in many places we didn't come across any issues.

Comment: It looks okay to use, its just user-defined naming conventions. Internally it is gonna get converted in actuall block definition only.

Comment: Is it only ever you who'll be maintaining it? You have the typedefs, is it really so hard to specify them...

Comment: @Wain From maintenance point of view, you can always drop a line of comment above which shows the actual declaration. And other dev can always dive into it to get the declaration.

Comment: @GoodSp33d but that might become out of date and a lie, and surely the comment is more effort than just defining the type. Good code is both easy to understand and does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:(MySuccessBlock)successBlock
                          failure:(MyFailureBlock)failureBlock;
```

Note the capitals at the beginning of `MySuccessBlock`and `MyFailureBlock` as in your typedef.

In fact, when you declare:

```
- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:mySuccessBlock
                          failure:myFailureBlock;
```

the problem comes from the fact that you don't specify the type of your parameters 'mySuccessBlock' and 'myFailureBlock'. So they are treated as default type `id` because:

> If a return or parameter type isn’t explicitly declared, it’s assumed
>   to be the default type for methods and messages—an id.

It is like if you write:

```
- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:(id)mySuccessBlock
                          failure:(id)myFailureBlock;
```

`id` type is a pointer, and blocks are pointers, so there is no compile problem. But you can have execution problem because of black's parameters and return value!

Comment: Didn't notice the typo (or may be it was not and thats why OP got some issues perhaps). This is the correct usage though. It should be the same method declaration in both `.h` and `.m` files. You can always expand the typedef too.

Comment: I have used "m" in "My" and it still compiles and run, no warning, no errors.  Does it make any differences?

Answer (score 0):

The typedef declaration provides a way to create an alias that can be used anywhere in place of a (possibly complex) type name. [See](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)

You should use the typedef in the following way.

```
- (void)myServiceWithCompletion:(MySuccessBlock)aSuccessBlock
                      failure:(MyFailureBlock)aFailureBlock;
```